# C# Calling Math Function from String

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I want to call `Math.Round()` and I've tried the following but it give me error

```
string mathFunc = "Round";

MethodInfo method = Math.GetType().GetMethod(mathFunc); // error
Console.WriteLine(method.Invoke(this, 1.78d));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see here you have 3 problems with your code

1. Math is class not a type so you should call `typeof(Math)` instead of  `Math.GetType()` to get the `Type`
2. Ambiguous method - [`Math.Round()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=netframework-4.8) as a-lot of overload, so you specify the overload that you want to use with [GetMethod(String, Type[])](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=netframework-4.8), for example **Math.Round(Double)**, so you should write  `MethodInfo method = typeof(Math).GetMethod(mathFunc, new[] {typeof(double) }) ;`
3. `method.Invoke(this,... )` should be replcaed with `method.Invoke(null, ..)`, although using this is acceptale Math.round is static, and the first object paramter will be ingoned anyway.

So full code can be something like this

```
            string mathFunc = "Round";    
            MethodInfo method = typeof(Math).GetMethod(mathFunc, new[] {typeof(double) }) ;         
            var res = method.Invoke(null, new object[] { 1.78d });
            Console.WriteLine(res);
```

> Output : 2

[dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ChIITj)

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `Math.GetType()`, you should use `typeof(Math)` to get the `Type` instance representing the type `Math`, because `Math` is a type, not an instance of a type.

Here are some more examples:

```
typeof(int) // ok, int is a type
5.GetType() // ok, 5 is an instance of int
typeof(5) // error, 5 is not a type
int.GetType() // error, int is not an instance
```

Although this isn't required, I would put the first argument to `Invoke` as `null`, because you are calling a static method:

```
Console.WriteLine(method.Invoke(null, 1.78d));
```

EDIT:

Just realised you still have some problems. `Round` has lots of overloads, so just using `GetMethod("Round")` is ambiguous. You have to specify the arguments' types as well (`double`).

The second parameter to `Invoke` is an `object[]`, so you need to create an array using the syntax `new object[] { ... }`.

```
string mathFunc = "Round";
MethodInfo method = typeof(Math).GetMethod(mathFunc, new[] {typeof(double) });
Console.WriteLine(method.Invoke(null, new object [] { 1.78d }));
```

Comment: Thanks but I want to call the `Round()` not check the number, can I?

Comment: @uingtea What do you mean by "check the number"? Which part of my answer says "check the number"?

Comment: @uingtea I have added the corrected code, which part do you not understand?

Comment: I understand now, but it it still error [check here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/N4KHvg)